# How to create a large ocean area using Bukkit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-worldedit

I use a Bukkit server for a personal Minecraft project, so I can use mods like WorldEdit, and have further configuration options than regular minecraft.

Recently, through using the MCEdit application, I preformed a "Prune" opperation on the map that I've been working on, to remove all of the excess areas on my map that I would never utilize. I essentially wanted to replace all of these areas with water, and after "Pruning" off the rest of the map, I was going to put the map back into my server and use WorldEdit to make this massive area of water.

When I put the map into my server, I was hoping that once i loaded the server up, it would only load the few select chunks that I had not deleted, but unfortunately, Bukkit spawned new chunks around the area I had saved.

I've tried a few mods, but none of them work because the Bukkit server automatically spawns into empty chunk spaces before it loads the plugins that would prevent this from happening.

**Is there any way to prevent this from happening, or otherwise create a large water area?** To be clear, any trick to making a water-world will work, it doesn't have to involve preventing chunks from being generated.

Comment: It doesn't answer your actual question, but if you've got MCEdit, can't you use a mass select / replace to make everything below height X water, then another one to make everything above height X air, then paste your creation back in?  For that matter, I'd be surprised of one of those command blocks I keep hearing about couldn't do that.

Comment: Well, Bukkit doesn't support use of command blocks, however the MCEdit option intruiges me. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: actually, I figured out how, and it seems to be working excellently for my uses. Submit your MCEdit answer and I'll select it as the answer to the question! :D

Comment: Just a nudge to let you know I'm editing your question (to make my answer you requested actually answer the question) ^_^

Comment: I think your original question suffered from what we call the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which is basically when you ask about your *attempted solution* to your problem (preventing chunks from being generated) instead of just asking about the problem itself (making a small water-world around your project).  This isn't to tell you that you're "doing StackExchange wrong" or anything like that, just to let you know how you might get better and faster answers in the future :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MCEdit's [tools](http://mcedit.wikia.com/wiki/Tools) should have at least one easy way to replace a large area with water or air, to make your ocean world with.  Just replace a big enough area around your project to make you happy, then prune everything past that :D

Looking at the options, Select and Fill should work, or possibly Create ocean chunks.